# git push: Out of memory, malloc failed /shared hosting

Tags: git, gitlab

I am trying to push my changes to git.

I get the following error message:

```
warning: suboptimal pack - out of memory
fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 255196924 bytes)
error: remote unpack failed: eof before pack header was fully read
```

I already searched for solutions and added the following to my git config:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
        packedGitLimit = 1024m
        packedGitWindowSize = 1024m
[pack]
        threads = 1
        deltaCacheSize = 1024m
    packSizeLimit = 1g
        windowMemory = 1024m
[http]
    postbuffer = 524288000
```

But that didn't help. I am using shared hosting so I can't increase RAM memory. Is there anything else I can do?

UPDATE:
I use revisr to use git in my wordpress and am trying to push it to gitlab.

Comment: just a side note: you don't push to git. You use git and push it to a remote hosting, which happens to be running git. Please state what software is running on the remote.

Comment: thanks! I use revisr to use git in my wordpress and am trying to push it to gitlab.

Comment: Don't use `http.postBuffer` unless you are certain you know what it does and that you need it, and read the Git FAQ first before you do.  Doing so is likely causing at least part of your problem.

Comment: Please, don't state relevant information in the comments, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63137316/edit) your question instead. There is no revisr tag in here, so please do state that in the main body